# Building permit minimum fees -- is there such a thing as a job "too small to permit" in some jurisdictions?

Tags: code-compliance, planning-permission

The electrical permits in my jurisdiction (Midwest USA city) run about $15 for a branch circuit off the top of my head (don't have the exact number, but it suffices for this question).  There are a few other fees added to them as well, but all in all, they do *not* add up to the $50 minimum fee requirement my jurisdiction imposes on permits.

Could it really be the case that the building department does not want people pulling permits for jobs the size of adding a single branch circuit to a house?  Or would it be legitimate to apply for a permit for a single branch circuit, and then give the building department $50 and say "keep the change"?

Comment: If they're sending out somebody to inspect the work, they have to cover their salary.  The $50 minimum, is likely what they *have* to charge to not lose money.

Comment: @Tester101 -- good point on not losing money to too-small permits -- I just wondered if there could be some legal implications for sending them money that isn't specific to an item listed on the permit app....

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel unfortunately that's a legal question, not a home improvement question.   Then again, for a $100k pool job, I knew more than the inspector that came 4 times.

Comment: @Tester101 their salary is already paid for by our taxes, we should not have to pay a dime for permits. They should scale the services provided to the funding available, eliminating all except life safety services if necessary. Government has no reason to be efficient unless **we demand it**.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it Let's keep politics out of it.

Comment: @JimmyFix-it In a perfect world, maybe... In the real world, taxes don't cover all of government spending. Governments have to find other ways to cover expenses, and permits are just one of those ways.

Answer (score 1):

My small town jurisdiction says you don't need a permit to change a toilet or do minor electrical work.